# Carregar páginas sem duplicar conteúdo através do AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

Possuo um sistema de navegação por *ajax* + *pushState* em meu site.
Se o usuário clicar em um link interno, será feito um `$.post` e eu verifico no PHP se `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST"` então eu carrego uma página, por exmplo: *indexPost.html*,
 e, se o usuário acessar diretamente o link eu faço um `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "GET"` então, carrego *indexGet.html*.

Segue abaixo o exemplo dos *indexe's*:

**indexPost.html**:

```
<p>Olá, esse é o conteudo!</p>
```

**indexGet.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>indexGet.html</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>Olá, esse é o conteudo!</p>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Tive que recorrer a desenvolver dessa maneira pois se carregasse, por exemplo, o *indexGet.html* através do `$.post` o arquivo HTML inteiro seria duplicado.

A minha pergunta é: existe alguma maneira mais simples de fazer isso sem ter que sempre ficar criando 2 arquivos para cada ação? Lembrando que, terei que fazer isso com vários arquivos, ou seja, seria um processo muito cansativo.

Acredito que há uma maneira mais simples, porém não consegui pensar em nada melhor que isso e além do mais, pesquisei e não encontrei exemplos alternativos.

**EDITADO**

Bem, segue um exemplo do que eu uso em meu sistema:

**index.php** (que é requisitada pelo `$.post` através do meu script):

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST") {
    $html = new Template("caminho/views/post/index.html");
    //aqui vão outras variáveis do template...
    $html -> show();
} else if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "GET") {
    $html = new Template("caminho/views/get/index.html");
    //aqui vão outras variáveis do template...
    $html -> show();
}
```

Estou utilizando um sistema de templates, e, como pode perceber, estou salvando o mesmo arquivo, porém em pastas diferentes, uma para cada caso.

No caso de ser *POST*, o *index.html* salvo em *caminho/views/post/index.html* possui apenas o conteúdo.

No caso de ser *GET*, o *index.html* salvo em *caminho/views/get/index.html* possui scripts e css's além do conteúdo.

**Obrigado!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A maioria dos sistema de template que conheço trabalham com o conceito de view e layout.

A view seria esse seu `indexPost.html` e o layout `indexGet.html`, com a impressão de uma variavel `$content` no lugar do conteúdo.

Normalmente esse layout é um html mais generico, com os menus do site, rodapé e coisas do tipo, e é usado por todas as outras views.

**Normalmente, se tem a opção de imprimir só a view, desabilitando o layout, que acredito ser o conteúdo que você quer quando recebe um "post".**

No seu caso, você poderia verificar se a requisição é um ajax, e desabilitar o layout.

Uma implementação bem simplista poderia ser essa.

`layout.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>indexGet.html</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        {CONTEUDO}
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

`example-view-hello-world.html`

```
Olá mundo
```

`example-view-stack.html`

```
Olá Stack
```

Função que faria o trabalho de renderizar as views com e sem layout.

```
function renderView($name, $layout = 'layout') {

    $viewHtml = file_get_contents("caminho/para/views/$name.html");

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === 'GET') {
        $layoutHtml = file_get_contents("caminho/para/views/$layout.html");
        $output = str_replace('{CONTEUDO}', $viewHtml, $layoutHtml);
    }
    else{
       $output = $viewHtml;
    }

   return $output;
}
```

Nesse sistema de template que você usa, esse conceito não é tão claro, mas esta previsto, ele é chamado de "usando vários arquivos html".

Basicamente, se você quer mostrar só a view, o código seria o seguinte:

```
$tpl = new Template('caminho/views/example-view-hello-world.html');
//aqui vão outras variáveis do template...
$tpl->show();
```

Caso você queria usar o layout, isso:

```
$tpl = new Template('caminho/views/post/layout.html');
$tpl->addFile('CONTEUDO', 'caminho/para/views/example-view-hello-world.html');
//aqui vão outras variáveis do template...
$html->show();
```

Com disse, o conceito de layout não é bem claro nesse sistema de template, mas deve funcionar.

Comment: Primeiramente, obrigado por responder. Bem, você citou vários exemplos, e acho que isso me confundiu um pouco... No primeiro exemplo da função que faria o trabalho de renderizar as views, eu não entendi o que vc fez, pq, pelo meu entendimento, vc carregou 2 arquivos diferentes, assim como eu já faço, pois você carrega o *$nome.html* e o *$layout.html*, então ficou meio confuso para mim... Poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Eu aproveitei e editei a pergunta, colocando mais dados, para que fique mais claro e de amplo entendimento.

Comment: Esse sistema de template que você esta usando não usa layouts?

Comment: Qual o sistema de template que você esta usando?

Comment: Utilizo esse: https://github.com/raelgc/template

Comment: editei a resposta, veja se ajuda.

Comment: Muito obrigado, através da sua resposta pude abrir minha mente para poder adaptar ao meu código. Eu já conhecia e utilizava o addFile() porém nem havia pensado em utilizar ele nesse caso, vai economizar muito espaço e linhas de código! Hehe. As vezes a resposta está na nossa frente e a gente não vê. Muito obrigado!